# issues with continuous x axis using ggpubr::lineplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, line-plot, ggpubr

I'm using ggpubr::lineplot to plot line plot. My x axis is continuous variable.

```
df <- data.frame(time=c(1, 5, 20),
                 len=c(4.2, 10, 29.5))
library(ggpubr)
ggline(df, x = "time", y = "len")
```

My time labels are equally spaced. It seems like lineplot treats time like factor instead of continuous variable.

Does anyone know how to correct that? I would like to use ggpubr::lineplot because it has many other functionalities. I know how to plot lines with just ggplot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `numeric.x.axis` argument is exactly for that!

```
ggline(df, x = "time", y = "len", numeric.x.axis = TRUE)
```

[image]